# Kendo Grid - sort checkbox filter example not working?

Tags: kendo-grid

This example  http://dojo.telerik.com/IsOTA/35 is supposed to show how to sort the checkbox list for a filter on a Kendo Grid ... but it doesn't actually work. (try it!)

Or what did I miss?

Comment: This question belongs somewhere on the [Telerik feedback](http://www.telerik.com/support/feedback) site, not Stack Overflow.

Comment: Perhaps, given how I phrased it, you are right. I suppose my intention was to ask for alternatives - but there is already a stack overflow question with an accepted  answer that uses the exact same principle: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31977583/how-to-order-a-kendo-grid-checkbox-column-filter-when-multi-and-columnmenu-are-b. If I had referenced that instead, would that be more acceptable?

Answer (score 0):

<del>[This solution in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31977583/how-to-order-a-kendo-grid-checkbox-column-filter-when-multi-and-columnmenu-are-b) works! The key difference seems to be in the use of BOTH</del>

`columnMenuInit` instead of `filterMenuInit`

AND

`.data("kendoColumnMenu")` instead of `.data("kendoFilterMultiCheck")`

<del>Which other solutions miss.</del>

EDIT:
Nope, just my small data set randomly coming back in the right order.

Comment: --aaand now it doesn't work. I'll be back when I figure out what is going on!!